# Can http://localhost:8080/tunnel-web/jsonws be opened on default installation?

Tags: java, json, web-services, liferay

I have error 404 if open http://localhost:8080/tunnel-web/jsonws on default Liferay installtion.

Aren't there any services registered by default?

**UPDATE**

My Liferay version is 6.0.6 (Bunyan / Build 6006 / February 17, 2011)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Liferay 6.1 RC, the path has changed to /api/jsonws (from tunnel-web/jsonws).

Most (if not all) public services should be registered by default.

Comment: This also does not work for me. But the following URL works for liferay.com site: http://www.liferay.com/tunnel-web/jsonws

Comment: Which version/build are you running?

Comment: Version 6.0.6 (Bunyan / Build 6006 / February 17, 2011)

Comment: Ah- that's why. jsonws is implemented as of 6.1.

Comment: So in 6.0.6 it is completely absent? Not just URL changed?

Comment: Correct. My answer that the "path has changed" was probably misleading. I meant to say that the path has changed from 6.1 beta to 6.1 RC. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was wishing my portlet to serve JSON requests for it's widget